# White space in Type name

Tags: c#

I've been using the TypeBuilder class to create dynamic types at runtime, and I've just noticed that it allows for type names that have space/white space in them.  So it produced a type called "Test Class" without any apparent problems.

It's for an application where the user can input their own type name, and so now I'm wondering whether allowing them to input space as part of the type name will cause problems down the road, or whether it should be fine.

Comment: You cannot use sapces in names with **C#**. The C# Compiler prevents you from doing that, But in CIL (IL, MSIL...) it's ok. However, if you want to prevent user from similar names, you simply just to test their name to make sure they match to the C# rules (by regex, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it won't cause any technical problem, it breaks a naming convention and introduces inconsistency (what is a problem down the road actually). For the sake of code readability and future maintenance I would not use them. If you need to differentiate between these types and regular ones, provide a descriptive suffix for those created in runtime.

Comment: Is there a particular set of rules I should adhere to?  As in: I'm sure white spaces aren't the only issue.

Comment: @ashaquick Here is the Microsoft guidelines about C# class naming. It explains rules to follow pretty exhaustively.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces

Comment: @Michael Powloka Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

.NET allows any unicode character in name. See ILAsm specification:

> II.5.3 Identifiers
>
> Identifiers are used to name entities. Simple
>   identifiers are equivalent to an ID. However, the ILAsm syntax allows
>   the use of any identifier that can be formed using the Unicode
>   character set (see Partition I). To achieve this, an identifier shall
>   be placed within single quotation marks. This is summarized in the
>   following grammar. [...]

More details in [Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf).

Problem arises when names should be used in other .NET languages. C# is a subset of ILAsm - anything in C# can be expressed in ILAsm. Opposite do not apply. **Some featuress of ILAsm are imposible to translate into C#, i.e. quoted names**.

C# names are described in [C# specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf). To simplify definitions in specification: identifiers should start with letter or underscore, followed by many letters, digits or underscores.

Conclusion: to keep .NET portability, use only names allowed in C#.